# How I call the method .call directly without instance it, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to call the method `.call` in a class service object, without instance it.

for instance:

`Product.new(my_args).call`

I would like to call such as:

`Product.call(my_args)`

for instance:

`Product.new(my_args).call`

I would like to call such as:

`Product.call(my_args)`

Comment: Are you asking "How can I create a singleton that I can call directly?" The [`Singleton`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/s?q=singleton) module gives you `.instance` and you can always delegate everything to that. Alternatively, if you really don't need multiple instances, just rework this as a `module` and define `self.call` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```rb
class ApplicationSevices
  def self.call(...)
    new(...).call
  end
end

class NameCreator < ApplicationSevices
  def initialize(nome)
    @nome = nome
  end

  def call
    puts "Nome: #{@nome}"
  end
end

NameCreator.call('Thiago')
```

See the post:
https://medium.com/@thiagolimadeveloper/calling-services-object-without-instance-in-ruby-ca8b3f95fd10

Comment: This does have the downside of creating a new instance each time it's called. If that's not desirable you can always lazy-initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common pattern in Ruby. You create a class method `.call` that creates an instance using the given arguments and then calls the instance method with the same name:

```rb
class Product
  def self.call(args)
    new(args).call
  end

  def initializer(args)
    # ...
  end

  def call
    # ...
  end
end
```